# Cannot modify header error when creating rest api in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I am trying to create a `REST API` which generate `json` data for `wordpress` posts. The code below is in *functions.php* file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'create_json_data', 0);
function create_json_data(){
    ob_start();
    if (isset($_GET['getjson'])  && $_GET['getjson'] == true) {
        if (have_posts()) {
            $data = array();
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                $new_data = array(
                    "title" => get_the_title(), 
                    "content" => get_the_excerpt(), 
                    "image" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(),
                    "hyperlink" => get_the_permalink()
                    );
                array_push($data, $new_data);
            }
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

It runs very well in newly `wordpress` installation. But when I implement it in my online website it gives me error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/public_html/blogsite/wp-content/themes/webtheme/header.php:10)
>   in
>   /home1/public_html/website-theme/wp-content/themes/webtheme/functions.php
>   on line 159

at line 10 in `header.php` is `wp_head()`

I don't know how to get ride of this error to generate `json` data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom AJAX action.
You will find everything you need on the codex :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Or you can use the Wordpress REST API plugin. It's allow you to create your own API endpoint.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/

**EDIT**
I give you a little example, with the jQuery ajax code to call it.

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_XXXXXX', 'ajax_XXXXXX');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_XXXXXX', 'ajax_XXXXXX');
function ajax_XXXXXX() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array(
        'text' => "Lorem ipsum dolor ...",
        'time' => time(),
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id()
    ));
    die();
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    method : "POST",
    data : {
        action : "XXXXXX"
    },
    success : function(datas) {
        console.log(datas);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you. but when I use this hook it does't return me any json data

Comment: I am trying at url `http://localhost:1234` by following your answer and it is returns whole page content instead of json data only.

Comment: It's weird, i've copy past my code on an empty wordpress i've on my localhost and it's work. Verify or ajax call URL. I've this :

`url : "http://127.0.0.1/wp-test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",`

Comment: and I am adding this `hook` in `functions.php` file. will this work?

Comment: All hooks need to be in the theme `functions.php`, or include in the main plugin's file.

Comment: thank you. I will let you know if this solved my question

Comment: After adding an empty file `admin-ajax.php` under the Wordpress root directory by following your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much bro